# image not display form UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL image path

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I selected image from photo library using `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL`, i got image path and assigned to `imageView.image` still not display that image, bellow is my code.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

  NSURL *refURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];     
  ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset) {

        ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];

        NSString *homeDirectoryPath = NSHomeDirectory();
        NSString *imagName = [imageRep filename];
        NSString *imagePath = [homeDirectoryPath stringByAppendingString:imagName];

        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,40,40)];
        imageView.image= [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagePath]]];

        UIView *aView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,50)];
        aView.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];

        [aView addSubview:imageView];
        [categoryDisplayScrollView addSubview:aView];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

      };

  ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
  [assetslibrary assetForURL:refURL resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage for getting image.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
        UIImage *imagepicked = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset) {

        ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];

        NSString *homeDirectoryPath = NSHomeDirectory();
        NSString *imagName = [imageRep filename];
        NSString *imagePath = [homeDirectoryPath stringByAppendingString:imagName];

        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,40,40)];
        imageView.image= imagepicked;

        UIView *aView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,50)];
        aView.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];

        [aView addSubview:imageView];
        [categoryDisplayScrollView addSubview:aView];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

      };

     ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
     [assetslibrary assetForURL:refURL resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:nil];

 }
```

Hope it helps you....!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo (NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

As mentioned in above code you can get UIImage from info dictionary with UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage key.

And next is assign this UIImage to UIImageView.